# Perl Smart Match not accepting string comparison

Tags: perl

Just dipping my toes into perl. I have a menu-based system whose input is handled by a given/when statement. While most of the my input is numbers, I want to be able to take "help" number as input and then spit out help for the particular number. I am trying to isolate the help section using regex to process the command, but smart match is expecting a number instead of string.

In another function, I have:

```
 my $MenuInput = <STDIN>;
 chomp $MenuInput;
 MenuProcess($MenuInput);
```

and then a subroutine to handle that input:

```
sub MenuProcess {
          my $value = @_[0];     
          given ($value){
                  when(1)         {CStatus()}
                  when(2)         {CInstall()}
                  when(3)         {CUpg()}
                  when(4)         {CDest()}
                  when(5)         {exit 0}
                  when($value =~ /help/)
                  {
                          print "help";
                  }

          }
 }
```

Eventually the 'print "help" will be replaced by handling for whatever particular menu option the user needs help with.

I am receiving this error

`Argument "help " isn't numeric in smart match at ./manage.pl line 59, <STDIN> line 1.`

I have `use 5.016;` specified and my perl -v output is as follows:

```
$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 34 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2012, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Comment: Your script works fine, you sure you pasted it verbatim?

Comment: Yes. I found that if I fail to enter anything I get the same kind of error, except help is replaced by a blank string:

`Argument "" isn't numeric in smart match at ./manage.pl line 59, <STDIN> line 1.`

Comment: The usual advice regarding `given` and `when` is not to use it. In the next version of Perl after yours—v5.18—it was marked as both experimental and deprecated, and you would get a warning message `given is experimental at ...` even if you don't enable warnings. It will not persist in its current form, and will  be either modified considerably or removed altogether before it loses its warning. You should use a chain of `if`/`elsif`/`else` instead, and you can wrap that in `for ( $value ) { ... }` as a topicaliser if you wish to deal with `$_` instead of `$value` directly.

Comment: You should also have seen a warning about `@_[0]` which should be `$_[0]`

Comment: @Borodin I changed it to that and am still receiving the same error.
I was using Switch to process this earlier but I saw that Switch doesn't handle regular expressions as well as given/when. If the general best practice is to not use I'll try to find another avenue for that.

Comment: If you mean the `Switch` module, then that was also deprecated in v5.12. It uses a source filter, which is never a good idea. Take a look at [*How do I create a switch or case statement?*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-do-I-create-a-switch-or-case-statement%3f)

Comment: The first recommendation on there is `given-when` which I'm avoiding based on your advice, then `if-else-elseif` which is cumbersome, but I guess I'll have to use since `Switch` is also deprecated.

Fairly annoying that Perl doesn't have anything not deprecated that's built-in. Other languages have Case statement support just fine.